# When asking for authorization to access the drive, all works well except it just doesn't redirect

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api, pydrive

I'm using pydrive to upload a pdf file to a google drive, all is working super well, except there's one very unpleasant issue.

When I click in allow, all works well in the background, but it just doesn't redirect anywhere. If I click again, it redirects but also gives an error.

I'm not sure if there's any code showing that could help. I use this for redirect_uri:

```
gauth.flow.redirect_uri = "http://localhost/accounts/oauth_validator"
```

This works btw, it works when I'm not asking for consent, it only doesn't work when asking for consent.

Is there any settings that I'm missing?

Comment: You have mentioned "If I click again, it redirects but also gives an error", could you share what error you have encountered?

Comment: I should have been more clear regarding that, it gives an error but it's an error that I catch and then it redirects because I'm telling it to redirect when it catches that error. However, I'm also telling him to redirect when no error is caught and yet it doesn't. This error is because when I click allow again, I'm using the same code again and that code is no longer valid, this is expected and the error is caught correctly.
I want to make clear that everything works perfectly, it's only when I'm giving consent that he doesn't redirect anywhere